# Web API's - how to select variables of interest in httr::get() request in R

Tags: r, httr

I'm learning to use APIs with R's `httr` package and the [US Data Census API](https://www.census.gov/data/developers/guidance/api-user-guide.Query_Examples.html) as my API.

When I make the request by manually entering the URL in the `GET()`,  the request works.

```
try_using_manual<- httr::GET("https://api.census.gov/data/2014/pep/natstprc?get=STNAME,POP&DATE=7&for=state:01&key=XXXX")

> try_using_manual
Response [https://api.census.gov/data/2014/pep/natstprc?get=STNAME,POP&DATE=7&for=state:01&key=7e3d28d2d9facb45c12a0b63f9d31b709d917dda]
  Date: 2018-12-08 03:08
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
  Size: 65 B
[["STNAME","POP","DATE","state"],
```

When I try to do the same request, but instead building arguments from the `GET()` function, my request fails.

```
> try_using_arg <- httr::GET(url = "https://api.census.gov/data/2014/pep/natstprc", 
+                  query = list("STNAME"=":*","POP"=":*","DATE"=7))
> try_using_arg
Response [https://api.census.gov/data/2014/pep/natstprc?STNAME=%3A%2A&POP=%3A%2A&DATE=7]
  Date: 2018-12-08 03:20
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
  Size: 74 B
```

Any ideas on how to call those variables, `STNAME`,`POP`,`DATE`,`state` as seen in `try_using_manual` in `try_using_arg`?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: The way that the API builds a URL from a query is abnormal. httr assumes that a query should encoded in the URL as follows: `key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3`. For example,  it created the following URL for your query - `https://api.census.gov/data/2014/pep/natstprc?STNAME=:*&POP=:*&DATE=7`. This obviously does not conform to the specification for how your API expects queries to be presented in the URL, so that's why you're getting an error. In other words, httr puts the query in to the URL in the typical form, but this doesn't conform to the form that the API is using.

Comment: @Chris OK - so maybe for API's that do not follow the key value query structure, use another tool? OK thanks I thought I was missing a big point here

Comment: I would just use the `GET` verb instead of `POST`, and create the urls yourself.

Comment: I am only using GET(), and haven't used POST() yet - do you mean something else?

Comment: oh sorry, i thought you were using post as well...i would just stick to get and construct the urls yourself